# Erc20 mint function for nft is giveing an ens when interacting using ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, mint

I am writing a marketplace and the mint function in the nft file is giving an error
`index.ts:261 Uncaught (in promise) Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getResolver", network="unknown", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.6.4)` i am able to connect to metamask using ethers and I can deploy using hardhat.

I know I have the contract stored in memory from the blockchain idk I just keep getting these errors I've been troubleshooting online. I've Redeployed and have switched out arguments idk it could be that im using a string i have cast to an int as the smart contract expects but still no luck to get the contract to mint any nft's. Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Which network are you using? Polygon, Optimism, Rinkeby, etc. Perhaps you are using a network where ENS hasn't been deployed yet.

Comment: hardhat Network

Comment: Similar issue https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102644/invalid-ens-name-when-running-hardhat-test. There was a github issue with the same error https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/issues/1289. It is likely you have an error in your code so an address is incorrectly initialized.